# open menu while clicking on checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox, menu

hey there i created this checkbox in comobination with a menu:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing"/><label for="thing"></label> 

        <ul class="sub-nav">
                <li>Johnny</li>
                <li>Julie</li>
                <li>Jamie</li>
        </ul>
```

style :

```
input[type=checkbox] {
display:none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label
{
background: #999;
height: 16px;
width: 16px;
display:inline-block;
padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label
{
background: #0080FF;
height: 16px;
width: 16px;
display:inline-block;
padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
.sub-nav {
    display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked > .sub-nav {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4huzr/71/

i want the sub-menu to open when you click at the grey checkbox(when you click again it should hide), but this sample doesnt work, anybody can help?

Answer (score 1):

The submenu is not a child of the input so `>` will not work.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kSR9C/1/)

The CSS should read

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sub-nav {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked > .sub-nav {
```

to:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sub-nav {
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4huzr/83/)**

[`>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) selects the child (which sub-nav isn't), where [`~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) is a general sibling selector.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a good plug and play component for anyone. You can always edit some css for anything else you need.

```css
.menu {
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.menu-label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*menu-label and menu-text have same padding*/

.menu-label {
  padding: 0 .5rem;
}

.menu-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-all;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .35s;
  -o-transition: max-height .35s;
  transition: max-height .35s;
  max-height: 0;
}

.menu-text {
  padding: 0 .5rem;
}

.menu-checkbox:checked~.menu-content {
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.menu-label::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  -o-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s;
}


/*codes from utf-8 dingbats*/

.menu-checkbox[type=checkbox]+.menu-label::after {
  content: "\2795";
}

.menu-checkbox[type=checkbox]:checked+.menu-label::after {
  content: "\2796";
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <input class="menu-checkbox" id="menu-toggle" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
  <label class="menu-label" for="menu-toggle">LABEL NAME</label>
  <div class="menu-content">
    <p class="menu-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It itaque.sdfsdfsdfsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</p>
  </div>
</div>
```